# What does error 112 (disk full) mean while writing on a serial port?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, serial-port, citrix

I'm getting a write error when writing to a serial port (COM1) on a Windows machine. The returned error is a 112 (DISK_FULL). As this is a serial port I don't get what the error means.

Could it be that the buffer is full? I don't think so as I'm getting the error on the first request I send after opening the port.

Comment: Which function are you using for writing to the COM port - [`WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) ?

Comment: Are you able tosend commands through TeraTerm?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: I don't have this info right now. I know we're using directly the Winbase api.

Comment: @Pramod: yes, we can communicate with other applications like Advanced Serialp Port Monitor without problems.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: you're right, we're using WriteFile.

Comment: Strange. Can you provide the code?

Comment: @Werner Henze: The code is pretty complex but has been working for years. They are drivers capturing data coming from medical devices. The error happened when we tried to map the COM port from the guest to a host in a Citrix session.

Comment: @SoMoS: If the code worked fine for years but fails with Citrix sessions, then I'ld tag the question with Citrix tag (if available) and point out that fact in the question. If you can extract the code that opens the COM port and does one (failing) WriteFile, it would be fine to see that code here to compare it against my own serial port code.

Comment: "What does error 112 (disk full) mean" is not a real question????? This has to be a joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I/O errors like that are generated by the device driver.  Which these days is rarely the standard Windows serial port driver provided by Microsoft, it only works on real serial port hardware.  Serial ports are very often *emulated* by device drivers that use custom hardware to implement communications.  Bluetooth and USB for example.  But anything goes.

It is convenient for the device manufacturer because they don't have to provide a custom DLL that lets you use the device in your own code.  Emulating a serial port lets you simply use the standard winapi functions to talk to the device.

But that's as far as it goes, a core problem is that you are not actually using serial port hardware.  And another is that these device manufacturers are not very good at writing custom drivers.  Particularly USB driver are notorious for their poor quality.  What doesn't help at all is that serial ports are not plug-and-play enabled, they are too primitive to support device discovery.  So simple things like discovering which port number is connected to a device and dealing with disconnecting the device while it is in use are serious obstacles.

So sure, a "disk full" error code doesn't mean anything.  The device driver writer grabbed the error code for some kind of error condition that's specific to the device.  The only way to find out what the error really means is to ask the vendor.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to fill a support request to Citrix as they created the driver that maps the guest phisical COM to the host 'virtual' port. Thanks, you rock.

Comment: The "Serial ports aren't PnP" is partially untrue, and more importantly irrelevant to this question. The device on the other side may not be identified, but the serial port on the computer side definitely can be PnP. For instance, those USB-to-serial port convertors are PnP on the PC side (plugging them in will load the correct serial port driver, but not the driver for the medical device)